# Closed form solution for constant exponent in sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for $\alpha$ in the following equation:

$$ 0.80 = \frac{1}{3} \left( X_1^\alpha + X_2^\alpha + X_3^\alpha \right)$$

Right now I just use Excel and solver to find a numerical solution to problems like these.  Seems like there should be a way to obtain a closed form solution.

This is an exponential curving example for grades that sets the average post-curved grade to 80%. Let me make it a bit more general:

$$ 0.80 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i^\alpha$$ where $n$ is the number of students that took the exam, $0 < X_i < 1$ is an exam grade for student $I$, and $0 < \alpha \le 1$ is a scaling factor.  Everything is known except $\alpha$.

This type of curving "gives to the needy and not the greedy" in that lower scoring students receive more of a bump yet the rank ordering is unchanged.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ in your case?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The unknown...

Comment: @DavidMoore You mention one equation and four variables/parameters. What is the variable you want to solve for? And what are the know parameters?\

Comment: @PierreCarre *"I am trying to solve for $\alpha$"*.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut My bad!

Comment: @DavidMoore Any assumptions / restrictions on $X_1,X_2,X_3, \alpha$? You need to solve this numerically but having these assumptions may help to setup an unconditionally convergent method.

Comment: I see no reason why there should be a closed-form solution.  By varying $\alpha$, we essentially obtain the [unit balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere#Unit_balls_in_normed_vector_spaces) in the 3-D vector space with the corresponding norm.  Equivalently, we create a closed surface that propagates like a wavefront.  We are asking, which value(s) $\alpha$ will make this surface touch a sphere with a certain radius.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses thus far.  Forgive me for not being more detailed in posting the question.  Hopefully the edits I just posted add clarity to the problem.

Comment: @PierreCarre Do the edits help clarify the problem?

Comment: ´@DavidMoore Chrystal clear!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you look for the zero of function
$$f(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^\alpha - nk$$ without loss of generality, suppose that the $X_i$ are such that $X_1\leq X_2\leq \cdots \leq X_n$.

So the solution is bounded
$$ \alpha_{min}=\frac{\log (k)}{\log (X_1)}\leq \alpha \leq  \frac{\log (k)}{\log (X_n)} =\alpha_{max}$$ with $f( \alpha_{min})>0$ and  $f( \alpha_{max})<0$.

Since $$f''(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^\alpha \log ^2(X_i)$$ is positive, start Newton method with $\alpha_0=\alpha_{min}$ and, by Darboux theorem, you will reach the solution without any overshoot of the solution.

Let us try with $n=6$, $k=0.8$ and $\{0.123,0.234,0.235,0.456,0.567,0.678\}$ for the $X_i$. You should get the following iterates

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \alpha_n \\
 0 & 0.106483 \\
 1 & 0.198764 \\
 2 & 0.205234 \\
 3 & 0.205263
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the fun of it, let us use $n=1000$ the $X_i$'s being normally distributed between $0.2$ and $0.8$ $(\mu=\frac 23,\sigma=\frac 13)$. This would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \alpha_n \\
 0 & 0.165337 \\
 1 & 0.348781 \\
 2 & 0.362371 \\
 3 & 0.362439 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form, for a provable reason.

Setting $t=X_1^\alpha$, the equation can be rewritten

$$t+t^p+t^q=c$$ where $p:=\dfrac{\log X_2}{\log X_1},q:=\dfrac{\log X_3}{\log X_1}$.

In general these exponents are fractional, but they can as well be integer. And it was proven that there is no general formula for the roots of a polynomial.

Comment: Hi Yves ! What could be a funny exercise is to work with a large number $n$ and assume that the $X_i$ follow a given distribution. If it is the normal one, I suppose that we should get a "nice" equation in $a$ with some error functions. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: deriving $X^\alpha$ when $X$ is uniform is tractable (gives a power law). And the sum amounts to a convolution. On another hand, for large $n$ the centered-reduced distribution tends to Normal, and maybe we can do with just the average and/or variance.

Comment: I am extremely bad in this  area (and in many other, be sure !). If you have time to waste, could you write the equation to solve ? It could be amazing. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: if I am right, the average of $X^\alpha$ (uniform in $[0,1]$) is just $1/(\alpha+1)$, while the variance is $1/(2\alpha+1)-1/(\alpha+1)^2$. This gives two estimates of $\alpha$ in terms of the $X_i$, independently of the LHS !?!

Answer (score 0):

Newton's method will converge in just a few iterations... Consider $f(x)=\frac 1n \sum_i X_i^{\alpha}-0.8$, $f'(\alpha)= \frac 1n \sum_i (\ln X_i) X_i^{\alpha}$ and implement the iteration
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha_0=1\\
\alpha_{k+1} = \alpha_k-\frac{f(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)}
\end{cases}
$$

You should reach machine precision in less then 10 iterations.